# Export multiple pandas dataframe in a single json object

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have multiple `pandas.DataFrame`s objects that I would like to dump in a single json string.

Let's say that I have the two following dfs:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]],
    index=["row 1", "row 2"],
    columns=["col 1", "col 2"],
    )

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"]],
    index=["Row 1", "Row 2"],
    columns=["Col 1", "Col 2", "Col3"],
    )
```

I want to export them in a single json string as:

```
{"df1":
    {"columns":
        ["col 1", "col 2"],
    "index":
        ["row 1", "row 2"],
    "data":
        [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
    },
"df2":
    {"columns":
        ["Col 1", "Col 2", "Col3"],
    "index":
        ["Row 1", "Row 2"],
    "data":
        [["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"]]
    }
}
```

## My tries

### Try 1

If I create a single dictionary in python containing both dataframes and then I pass it to `json.dumps`, I receive a `TypeError` since `json` does not know how to serialize a `pandas.DafaFrame`:

```
out = {'df1': df1,
       'df2': df2
       }
out = json.dumps(out) #<-- Raises TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable
```

### Try 2

If I serialize each df individually using the `pandas.DataFrame.to_json` method as

```
df1_jsonstr = df1.to_json(orient='split')
df2_jsonstr = df2.to_json(orient='split')

out = {'df1': df1_jsonstr,
       'df2': df2_jsonstr
       }
out  = json.dumps(out)
```

The output looks like:

```
{"df1": "{\"columns\":[\"col 1\",\"col 2\"],\"index\":[\"row 1\",\"row 2\"],\"data\":[[\"a\",\"b\"],[\"c\",\"d\"]]}", "df2": "{\"columns\":[\"Col 1\",\"Col 2\",\"Col3\"],\"index\":[\"Row 1\",\"Row 2\"],\"data\":[[\"A\",\"B\",\"C\"],[\"D\",\"E\",\"F\"]]}"}
```

Both strings generated by `pandas.DataFrame.to_json` have been escaped and quoted. When I try to load them back doing `data = json.loads(out)`, the two dataframes are considered (correctly) strings and are loaded as such.

### Try 3

The only way I found to generate the json file I want is to dump the dataframe to json using `pandas.DataFrame.to_json`, then load them back into dictionaries with `json.loads` and then dump them again together. This looks like:

```
df1_json = df1.to_json(orient='split')
df2_json = df2.to_json(orient='split')

out = {'df1': json.loads(df1_json),
       'df2': json.loads(df2_json)
       }
out = json.dumps(out)
data = json.loads(out)
```

This works, but if `df1` and `df2` have hundreds of thousands or millions of lines, you can understand that this performs the conversion three times (`pd.DataFrame` -> `str` -> `dict` -> `str`) becoming inefficient.

## Question

Is there a way to achieve the same result as my last example, but performing a single conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do something like:

```
out = """
       {
          "df1": """ + df1.to_json(orient='split') + """,
          "df2": """ + df2.to_json(orient='split') + """
       }
"""
```

or:

```
df1_json = df1.to_dict()
df2_json = df2.to_dict()

out = {'df1': df1_json
       'df2': df2_json
       }
out = json.dumps(out)
data = json.loads(out)
```

Comment: You just edited your answer to be the same as mine...

Comment: Good for you, tracking these kind of things)) Have you tracked also, that the idea of constructing string was before your answer?

Comment: I accepted this answer, as at the end of the day it's the best I could find, but it's not problem-free. While df.to_json recursively serialise all elements in the dataFrame, to_dict() unpacks the dataframe in a dictionary (that is json-able) but other things, like DateTimeIndex, Interval Index, etc will remain and need to be handled manually, otherwise json.dumps fails as it doesn't know how to serialize these.